# Google Beacon API - Diagnostics Calls Fail

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, beacon, proximity

I am at a complete loss here...The two calls bellow are using the same service yet one works great the other fails...I was hoping another set of eyeballs might catch something I am doing wrong.  On the google OAuth Playground they both seem to be working fine

```
    !! CRASHES !!
//Googles Class
class Google_Service_Proximitybeacon_BeaconsDiagnostics_Resource extends Google_Service_Resource
{
  public function listBeaconsDiagnostics($beaconName, $optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array('beaconName' => $beaconName);
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('list', array($params), "Google_Service_Proximitybeacon_ListDiagnosticsResponse");
  }
}

//Service
$service = new Google_Service_Proximitybeacon($client);

//Call
$beaconName = 'beacons/3!f7826da64fa24e9880243rgenfgv43kgekfe';
$request = $service->diagnostics->listBeaconsDiagnostics($beaconName);


!! WORKS GREAT !!
//Googles Class
class Google_Service_Proximitybeacon_Namespaces_Resource extends Google_Service_Resource
{
  public function listNamespaces($optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array();
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('list', array($params), "Google_Service_Proximitybeacon_ListNamespacesResponse");
  }
}

//Service
$service = new Google_Service_Proximitybeacon($client);

//Call
$request = $service->namespaces->listNamespaces();
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listBeaconsDiagnostics() on null in /home/xtractio/public_html/test4.php:121 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/xtractio/public_html/test4.php on line 121

This is the fatal error I am receiving, just odd that both the calls above and other calls are pretty much identical but these two extended classes attachments/diagnostics seem to be causing the most issue.

Thanks in advance!